# How do I make a vim color scheme work with gvim?

Tags: vim

I am trying to use this color scheme
https://github.com/goatslacker/mango.vim

It works when I open vim from the command line. But I usually open files from the file manager GUI and that opens them in gvim. The color scheme displays a white background in gvim. How do I fix it so it displays a dark background?

I've looked at the `mango.vim` file and it has the line `set background=dark` but apparently that is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim separates between term, cterm (color terminal) and gui since they are capable of handling different numbers of colors

mango.vim only gives highlighting instructions for cterm. If it were for gui aswell it would look like this:

```
 hi Comment term=bold ctermfg=Red guifg=Red0
```

So if your color-scheme lacks gui support it will reset to default.

Comment: The maintainer's contact details should be at the top of the colorscheme file. I'd suggest sending them a polite email asking for gvim support.